# How to change api URL attributes(values) in SLIM

Tags: rest, pagination, slim

I am doing pagination in REST api developed over slim.
Using below API to get current uri

```
(string) $request->getUri();
```

RESULT ::http://localhost/slim/test_app/test/public/api/actions/?page=2

But now for next request i need to replace the page number in current url to (+1) ie 3 here and pass in data returned to user like below

```
{
"data":[
//data
]
"next": http://localhost/slim/test_app/test/public/api/actions/?page=3
}
```

What could be the best way to replace the page number ? Do we have any direct api for this,to just replace the attributes ?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Do you want to generate a new URL (to page 3) on server side (which is responding to API calls) and send it back to client (who has sent a request for page 2) so the client knows which URL should be used for the next call? Or is this all on client side? How is the URL to current page (page 2) generated?

Answer (score 0):

I added a function to merge attributes and than bind the query to url as below function

```
private function merge_querystring($url = null,$query = null,$recursive = false)
    {
      if($url == null)
        return false;
      if($query == null)
        return $url;
      // split the url into it's components
      $url_components = parse_url($url);
      // if we have the query string but no query on the original url
      // just return the URL + query string
      if(empty($url_components['query']))
        return $url.'?'.ltrim($query,'?');
      // turn the url's query string into an array
      parse_str($url_components['query'],$original_query_string);
      // turn the query string into an array
      parse_str(parse_url($query,PHP_URL_QUERY),$merged_query_string);
      // merge the query string
      if($recursive == true)
        $merged_result = array_merge_recursive($original_query_string,$merged_query_string);
      else
        $merged_result = array_merge($original_query_string,$merged_query_string);
      // Find the original query string in the URL and replace it with the new one
      return str_replace($url_components['query'],http_build_query($merged_result),$url);
    }
```

and i use below to add query to url

```
    $postQuery["page"]=$currentpage+1;
    //print_r($postQuery);
    //echo http_build_query($postQuery);
    $data["next"]= $this->merge_querystring($request->getUri(),"?".http_build_query($postQuery));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace pagination value by string manipulation. But you can also using what Slim provide.

`Slim\Http\Uri` class, which implements `Psr\Http\Message\UriInterface`, has `withQuery()` method that will replace current query string.

It will return cloned `Slim\Http\Uri` instance with its query string replaced.

```
$query = $request->getQueryParams();
$query['page'] = $query['page'] + 1;
$url = $request->getUri();
$nextUrl = $url->withQuery(http_build_query($query));
$data['next'] = (string) $nexUrl;
```